# how to get what type of activation is used?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, activation-function

I have found that `model.layers[index].output` prints the info I need. But, I couldn't get what activation function was used by looking at this output:
`Tensor("dense_11_1/clip_by_value:0", shape=(?, 256), dtype=float32)`

Usually, it is like `Tensor("block5_conv3_1/Relu:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 512), dtype=float32)` and I can see  **Relu** was used in that layer.

How to determine the activation function of the above-look output?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try model.layers[index].activation ?

Comment: didn't really think of it, silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think, layers with activations will expose them with the `activation` attribute, so you can do:

```
model.layers[index].activation
```

And should give you information about the activation used by that layer.